# Choice of hypersurface in Klein-Gordon inner product

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let $M$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Consider the covariant Klein-Gordon equation

$$(g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+m^{2})\phi=0$$

Define the following indefinite inner product on the space of its solutions:

$$(f,h):=\int_{\Sigma} d^{3}x \sqrt h n^{\mu} (f^{*}\partial_{\mu}h-h\partial_{\mu}f^{*})$$

where $\Sigma$ is a spacelike Cauchy surface, $h$ is the determinant of the induced metric $h_{ij}$ on $\Sigma$ and $n_{\mu}$ is the unit vector, orthogonal to the hypersurface.

In chapter 9 of "Spacetime and geometry" by Carroll and in chapter 3 of "Quantum fields in curved space" by Birrell and Davies, it is said that this quantity is independent of the choice of $\Sigma$.

Let's consider two different spacelike Cauchy surfaces, $\Sigma_{1}$ and $\Sigma_{2}$: they say that it can be proven, via Gauss' theorem, that the integral is the same, using any of the two hypersurfaces.

This is clear to me, in the case in which $\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}$ is the boundary of a four-volume $\Omega$.

However, I don't understand how to extend the reasoning to the case where $\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}$ does not correspond to the boundary of a four-volume $\Omega$, in the sense that the volume must be closed with an additional border piece, i.e. another hypersurface $\Sigma_{3}$, such that $\partial\Omega=\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}+\Sigma_{3}$. Maybe, the solution is that the volume can be closed in such a way that the integrand goes to zero in this additional piece.
Why should it go to zero?

In "Quantum field theory in curved spacetime" by Ford, for example, it is said that, if necessary, we can close the volume with timelike boundaries on which $f=h=0$, but I don't understand why we can assume the solutions must be null on this boundary. For example, in flat spacetime, we have plane wave solutions, that do not go to zero anywhere.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but that inner product is probably defined on functions that decay sufficiently fast, so that you can close the volume at infinity with no problem. Plane waves are not normalizable.

Comment: I think it is typically assumed that the functions considered have compact support on hypersurfaces (although it is not specified in the cited references). As far as I know, this is the setting in which one works when addressing the problem in a formal way. What I'm wondering is: is it necessary to require solutions to have compact support on hypersurfaces to demonstrate this? The question arises from the observation that it is not indicated in the two references, as if it were not necessary.

Comment: Oh, I understand the problem. I'm pretty sure that surface has to be a Cauchy surface, not any spacelike hypersurface. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it is, I'll correct the question. I think my problem is related to the solution space.  For some reason I don't want to accept that we have to work with solutions that have compact support on Cauchy surfaces and I hope I can get rid of this hypothesis. The point is that in the specific case of a flat space, we always use plane waves, which have no compact support on Cauchy surfaces. So I don't understand why in that specific case we can get rid of that hypothesis, while in the more general case, which should contain the first, we have to impose it.

Answer (score 0):

One usually assumes that the functions going in the inner product have compact support. Thus, the integral only has contributions in a compact region of the hypersurfaces $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Therefore, you just have to pick a timeline $\Sigma_3$ that is sufficiently far away from the supports os the functions being integrated and you'll have that the integral over this hypersurface must vanish.